# How to create a default python submodule for import

Tags: python

I'm using python settings files. I have the following structure:

```
settings
├── base.py
├── __init__.py
├── local.py
├── production.py
└── staging.py
```

The settings module is picked up from an environment variable e.g 'settings.production'. This works fine and replaces the old inflexible settings.py file allowing me to have the settings for the staging, production and local sites all nicely organised.

A `settings = importlib.import_module(os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'])` in the calling code picks up my new flexible settings as if they were the old module which is cool and it works most of the time.

Unfortunately, old legacy code, of which there is a lot, now and then calls 'import settings' and this fails.

I need 'import settings' to be exactly equivalent to 'import settings.production', or whatever is specified in the environment variable, in order to support the legacy code without losing the benefits of the flexible settings configuration.

*Note: Yes this is me working with an old and very large Django 1.3 site but I believe I've made this question independent of Django.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing up this question was cathartic. Here is my solution:

In the `__init__.py` for the settings module I put:

```
import os
import importlib
try:
    # Do a dynamic 'from DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE import *'
    settings = importlib.import_module(os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'])
    for v in dir(settings):
        if v.startswith("__"): continue
        globals()[v] = getattr(settings, v)
except ImportError, KeyError:
    # default to the production settings if environment variable not set or improperly specified
    from production import *
```

This does do a little extra work but it solves the problem nicely. Now my legacy programs get the required settings.

In essence this makes `import settings == import settings.xxx` where `settings.xxx` is specified in the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.

*I hope someone else finds this useful. Note that newer versions of DJANGO make this shenanigans unnecessary as long as the applications you make use of import the settings properly.*